# Edit or replace background image or video link

Tags: video

I am new to Blender (learning to navigate, viewports, etc..). I have the file as I want it but I just need to change the link for the video background/image that is already set with another one (so another video/image replaces the actual one). Same dimensions, position, etc. Just the link needs changing. Can I do it without deleting the image/video and importing a new one (re-position it, declare the dependencies, etc.)? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Just click the folder icon next to the cross on that image node and it will bring up the file selector to select your new file. Assuming the video/image dimensions are the same you shouldn't need to change anything else. If you do have a problem you can go back to the old one by selecting it again from the dropdown by the image icon.

Comment: Actually opening and changing textures and many other things in nodes and other selection fields is a very basic function. I don't mean this rude, but I guess should really watch some beginner tutorials on how to use the common features in Blender.

Comment: Thank you so much. The folder thing I didn't noticed it until you pointed out. I was like..duhh.. It works now flawless. And yes, I need to start getting into some serious training for beginners. Am rendering it as we speak. Thank you again.